# Drupal: why can't user admin access my module pages?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I am working on a drupal 6.x module which consists of several page as defined in the .module page. The problem is that when I visit those pages as admin, I get access denied. I thought that admin (user 1) could access anything? Here the code for some of the pages:

```
function foobar_menu()
{
 $items['admin/foobar'] = array(
   'title' => 'administer foobar',
   'page callback' => 'foobarpage',
 );

 $items['admin/foobar/baz'] = array(
   'title' => 'Do baz',
   'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
   'page arguments' =>array('foobarpage'),
 );
```

**So how do I make sure that only admin can see these pages and the rest get a "page does not exists" error?**

EDIT: I found solution [here](http://drupal.org/node/96928).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define `access arguments` for every single menu item.

See [drupal.org documentation](http://drupal.org/node/109157) on this subject.

For example you hook_menu may look something like this:

```
$items['admin/foobar'] = array(
    'title' => 'administer foobar',
    'page callback' => 'foobarpage',
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
);
```

Comment: But admin cannot have permissions assign to him, right? I mean, there is no Administrator column on the permissions page.

Comment: Admin always has all permissions. If you want only admin to have the "administer site configuration" permission, simply don't assign it to anyone else.

Comment: Scott is correct. In any case I would not be making it a habit of giving out the above permission out to random people on your site. If you trust them to change site configuration, then surely you trust them to visit your module's page. If that is only user #1, then so be it.

Comment: But I don't want OTHER users to access the pages, just admin. If admin has that access by default, why cannot I use those pages when logged in as admin?

Comment: You should use hook_perm to define a new permission (e.g. "administer foobar"), and only give that permission to users who you want administering foobar. If you (e.g. uid 1) are the only one, then don't give that permission to anyone. In either case, having 'access arguments' defined is key.

Comment: I just defined an access callback function and check that user is admin:  if(user_access('administer'))
 {
  return true;
 }

Answer (score 1):

wiifm's answer is correct, but the other alternative (if you don't want to use 'administer site configuration') is to create a custom access callback function that checks either uid == 1 or create a custom priv.

I don't know what is best for your case, but chances are you want to do as wiifm suggests.

Comment: But I don't want OTHER users to access the pages, just admin. If admin has that access by default, why cannot I use those pages when logged in as admin?

Answer (score 0):

When you say admin, you mean the first user you created o a specific user that you gave all privileges. In anyway, as wiifm said above, even for admin, you must add the 'access argument' entry in your menu items, once you do that, and if you do what wiifm says, you should be able to access the menu item with admin and not with any other user (unless you give that permission to other users, which is unlikely).